# Having jQuery trouble with adding a class on scroll up

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-waypoints

If you look below I'm adding a several classes at offset -185, two are animated/fadeIn when you scroll down.  I'd like to have the bar fadeOut when you scroll up past the offset but I'm having trouble achieving this.  I'm using jQuery waypoints script http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/

```
$('#wrapper').waypoint(function(event, direction) {
    $('#scroll-action').toggleClass('hidden', direction === "up");
}, {
    offset: -185
}).find('#scroll-action').waypoint(function(event, direction) {
    $('#scroll-action').removeClass('hidden');
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('sticky', direction === "down");
    $('#scroll-action').addClass('animated fadeIn');
    event.stopPropagation();
}, {
    offset: -185
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should simplify it a bit it will make it easier to fix your issue.  You will need to swap out with your logic, but simplifying it to only use waypoint with the `#wrapper` I think is the way to go.  When you scroll down and `#wrapper` is 185px above the window then fade in `#scroll-action`.  When you scroll up then fade out.  I think putting waypoint also on `#scroll-action` may be causing the two to conflict.

```
$(function() {
  $('#wrapper').waypoint(function(event, direction) {
    if(direction === "up") {
      $('#scroll-action').fadeOut();
    } else {
      $('#scroll-action').fadeIn();
    }
  }, { offset: -185});
});
```

[Here's a jsFiddle that is similiar to what you are doing, so you can see this in action.](http://jsfiddle.net/qNF6k/)  Make sure you make the HTML window kind of small.

Comment: Gave that a shot with this, it's not adding the class. Any ideas?

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $('#wrapper').waypoint(function(event, direction) {
    if(direction === "up") {
      $('#scroll-action').fadeOut();
    } else {
   $('#scroll-action').addClass('sticky');
      $('#scroll-action').fadeIn();
    }
  }, { offset: -185});
});
</script>

Comment: Can you post your HTML or a snippet of what it's like?